# Adding imageurl in database design in hierarchial approach

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am trying to create an application like Facebook in which each user can create multiple albums and then place photos inside it. Users can also comment on the photos, so I need to make a database where `album_name`, `pic_name`, then `comments` on the pic will be applied.

I have a concept but I don't know whether it is feasible or not.

Here is my user table schema:

#### candidate_register_table

```
|----------------------------------------------------|
|   username  |  name   |  age   | sex   | password  |
|----------------------------------------------------|
```

A record would look like this:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   saz26  |  Saswat Routroy   |  26   | Male   | Saswat  |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

Now I want to create a table holding the `album_names` for each user creating albums.

Say the table name is `saz26_albums`, where saz26 is the username in the candidate_register_table, (I am concatenating the username with the string "_albumname" to create a table) the schema of this table will be like this:

```
|------------------------------|
| album_name  |  cover_pic     |
|------------------------------|
```

A tuple in the above table will look like this:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Candidate_Pics/Male/saz26/MyPics  |Candidate_Pics/Male/saz26/MyPics/2.jpg|
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

That means, for each username, a new table username_albums will be created holding the path of each albums(folder) he creates:

Another table with the name saz26_pics will be created with the following schema:

```
|------------------------------------------|
| pic_name  |  album_name      | caption   |
|------------------------------------------|
```

For example like this:

```
|------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|----------|
| Candidate_Pics/Male/saz26/MyPics/1.jpeg  |  Candidate_Pics/Male/saz26/MyPics | At Sea   |
|------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|----------|
```

Now, the last part, which definitely needs a table for each picture, I mean that a table denoting a single pic, and it contains all the usernames, and their corresponding comments given by them.

Say for example, a table with name:

saz26_MyPics/1_comments

```
|----------------------------|
| username  |  comments      |
|----------------------------|
```

For example like this:

```
|----------------------------------|
| suhani18  |  Where is this place |
|----------------------------------|
| saz26     |      Dead Sea        |
|----------------------------------|
```

I don't know whether any other possible design can be achieved, I just want someone to let me know any other possibilities. If any other possibilities not present, then is my design feasible enough?

Some people told me to maintain a schema somewhat like this by creating a table albums:

```
|-----------------------------------------|
| username  |  album_name | cover_pic     |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

This doesn't solve my problem which is how to maintain comments on each picture. Because some pictures can have 200 comments, some 3 comments and some will have no comments at all.

Comment: Off the bat I would say you need to link the id (nonexistent) or username to the album in a seperate column rather than creating a table per album. Just have all the albums in one table called albums.

Comment: @JamesHay, the problem is how to maintain all the commentz in each pic under a database table?? what u have said is ok, but the level 3 approach of holding the commentz, is quite tricky

Comment: Putting an age old question on hold? Why such an outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need four tables: `users`, `albums`, `pics` and `comments`. Each table should have an `id` column of type `int`, with `auto_increment`, and set as the primary key for the table.

Then on table `albums` you have a `user_id` column for the album owner. On `pics`, you have an `album_id`, and on `comments` you have both `pic_id` and `user_id` (all `int` columns, preferably indexed).

With such a structure, you can easily retrieve you data using [SQL JOINS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

**UPDATE**

Since `username` is already a PK on the users table, you can use that instead of `user_id` in `albums` and `comments`.

About the comments table: it seems to me that it only needs 3 columns: `username` (the user who made the comment), `pic_id` (the id of the picture the comment refers to), and `comment` (the comment itself).